# Imputing variables recursively or sequentially in Tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following dataset:

[image]

I want to calculate impute the NA in the n_j column in the second row with the formula
n_j - (d_j+c_j).

To create the data:

```
    df = structure(list(time_intervals = structure(1:8, levels = c("[0,12)",
"[12,24)", "[24,36)", "[36,48)", "[48,60)", "[60,72)", "[72,84)",
"[84,96]"), class = "factor"), d_j = c(16L, 10L, 1L, 3L, 2L,
2L, 0L, 2L), c_j = c(4L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L), n_j = c(48L,
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df",
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I managed to do this with a *for* loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df <- df |>
    mutate(
    n_j =
      ifelse(is.na(n_j), lag(n_j)- (lag(d_j)+lag(c_j)), n_j)
  )
}
```

Is there a way to do this using *purrr::map* or other [Tidyverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidyverse) functions?

Comment: Note: [Imputing](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/impute#Verb) is not a typo - *"5. (transitive, statistics) To replace missing data with substituted values."*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use:

```
 start <- df$n_j[1]
 transform(df, n_j = c(start, start - cumsum(d_j + c_j)[-nrow(df)]))
```

Output:

```
  time_intervals d_j c_j n_j
1         [0,12)  16   4  48
2        [12,24)  10   4  28
3        [24,36)   1   0  14
4        [36,48)   3   1  13
5        [48,60)   2   2   9
6        [60,72)   2   0   5
7        [72,84)   0   1   3
8        [84,96]   2   0   2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I was looking for something in the tidyverse

Comment: @AbdullahAbdelaziz just change `transform` to `mutate` ie `df %>%mutate(n_j = c(n_j[1], n_j[1] - cumsum(d_j + c_j)[-n()]))` there is no much difference

Comment: @AbdullahAbdelaziz, why would you eschew a one-liner answer like this? There are certainly times when `dplyr`-based answers can be more elegant, easier, faster, etc ... this is not one of them. I suggest against blindly assuming anything non-tidyverse is too hard, not good enough, or something else.

Answer (score 13):

**A one-liner with `dplyr`**

We can fill the NAs from the original column with `coalesce()`. The replacement comes from subtracting the lagged `d_j` and `c_j`.
Finally, use a `cum`mulative `sum` to obtain the desired output.
It should be fairly efficient, because this relies on vectorized subtractions and the very fast `cumsum`.

```
df |>
    mutate(n_j = coalesce(n_j, -lag(d_j) -lag(c_j)) |> cumsum())
# A tibble: 8 × 4
```

Output:

```
  time_intervals   d_j   c_j   n_j
  <fct>          <int> <int> <int>
1 [0,12)            16     4    48
2 [12,24)           10     4    28
3 [24,36)            1     0    14
4 [36,48)            3     1    13
5 [48,60)            2     2     9
6 [60,72)            2     0     5
7 [72,84)            0     1     3
8 [84,96]            2     0     2
```

Answer (score 6):

One solution using `accumulate2` from `purrr` is:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(
    n_j = accumulate2(
      d_j,
      c_j,
      ~..1 - (..2 + ..3),
      .init = first(n_j)
    )[-n()-1]
  )
```

**Output**

```
  time_intervals   d_j   c_j   n_j
  <fct>          <int> <int> <int>
1 [0,12)            16     4    48
2 [12,24)           10     4    28
3 [24,36)            1     0    14
4 [36,48)            3     1    13
5 [48,60)            2     2     9
6 [60,72)            2     0     5
7 [72,84)            0     1     3
8 [84,96]            2     0     2
```

Answer (score 4):

Another solution using `accumulate`:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(n_j = accumulate(
    .init = first(n_j),
    .x = seq_len(n() - 1),
    .f = ~ ifelse(is.na(df$n_j[.y + 1]), .x - (df$d_j[.y] + df$c_j[.y]), df$n_j[.y + 1])
  ), .keep = "unused")
```

Output:

```
 time_intervals   d_j   c_j   n_j
  <fct>          <int> <int> <int>
1 [0,12)            16     4    48
2 [12,24)           10     4    28
3 [24,36)            1     0    14
4 [36,48)            3     1    13
5 [48,60)            2     2     9
6 [60,72)            2     0     5
7 [72,84)            0     1     3
8 [84,96]            2     0     2
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want *"recursive"* or *"iterative"* things, you can try `Reduce` like here

```
transform(
  df,
  n_j = head(
    Reduce(`-`,
      d_j + c_j,
      init = n_j[1],
      accumulate = TRUE
    ), -1
  )
)
```

which gives

```
  time_intervals d_j c_j n_j
1         [0,12)  16   4  48
2        [12,24)  10   4  28
3        [24,36)   1   0  14
4        [36,48)   3   1  13
5        [48,60)   2   2   9
6        [60,72)   2   0   5
7        [72,84)   0   1   3
8        [84,96]   2   0   2
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the lag function:

```
Mutate(N_j = ifelse(is.na(n_j), lag(n_j,1) - (d_j + c_j), n_j))
```

If I understand correctly, this will give you what you wanted, which is the NJ from the previous row (otherwise all is na) minus the sum of DJ and CJ of the specific row.

Comment: It will do this only for the second row